# What is the maximum resolution of an 'img' in a Windows Store App?

Tags: image, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm writing a windows store app, which uses a zoomable/pannable div to show a large image and allow a user to locate specific sections within the image.

Through this work I've been provided an (admittedly huge) image (from a design house) which does not render when set as the img.src (loaded via a blob from a storage file object). It just shows a plain white screen where the image should be.

The image in question is > 35000 pixels wide and about 11000 high.

I've established that re-saving the image (as large as Fireworks would let me!) with a 10000 pixel width renders as expected.

I'd like to go back to the design guys and let them know the maximum size that the app will support, but I can't find this information anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas as to the limits here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid the limits might be determined by available RAM on the video card or other runtime factors. They might also be different depending on the image encoding (e.g. jpeg, png, ...) and file size. I would make sure to test this on a number of different devices, including ARM devices.

Comment: When decoded, your image will be 1.4 GB in size (4 bytes per pixel times width time height). I wouldn't be surprised that a graphics card has problems dealing with this.

Comment: Hmm, whilst these seem sensible remarks, I'm not 100% convinced. The 35,000 x 11,000 image is only 2MB in size, and saving the image down to 10,000 x 3,800 it's only 1MB. When loading the 10,000px image in the tablet simulator my memory usage goes from 1.4GB to 1.5GB, which whilst not ideal doesn't seem like it would bring things to it's knees.

Comment: It's not the size of the file that is important, it's the size of the decompressed pixels. A video card can't render a JPEG encoded stream, it needs to be decoded to get the pixels. Those may not show up in your memory measurement, since they sit on the video card, not your virtual memory address space.

Comment: What is the nature of this image? Why does it need to be stored as one big bitmap? Can you tile it, or use vector graphics?

Comment: Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/09/12/using-hardware-to-decode-and-load-jpg-images-up-to-45-faster-in-internet-explorer-11.aspx

Comment: If past IE experience is valid, then I'd add, while there may be a theoretical limit of ###, the reality is that many other difficult to measure factors come into play (including RAM pressure, other images, DOM, etc.) that affect the actual *practical* limits. I'd strongly suggest tiling the image if possible.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Thanks for the info. Regarding the image, it serves as a map, it's essentially a floor plan. The client requires seamless panning/zooming so the option to tile it will be a hard sell. It's odd that I can load the image quite happily in another 32 bit app, such as IE without such an issue. 
We have tried using vector graphics, but the number of artifacts becomes an issue. The same source image converted to SVG for example is > 60MB in size, and doesn't even render in IE after several minutes :s
We're working on an optimised flattened PDF version but for the time being it's png